# Echo php as image

Tags: php, image

I could use some help here, because I cannot figure out how to echo a php row (a URL) as a link to an image.

**This is the code I already have**

```
echo"<table border=1>
                            <tr>
                                <th width=80px>Release</th>
                                <th width=250px>Title</th>
                                <th width=200px>Genre</th>
                                <th width=200px>Developer</th>
                                <th width=200px>Publisher</th>
                                <th width=100px>Links</th>
                            </tr>";

                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                           {
                            echo"
                            <tr>
                                <td>{$row['game_release']}</td>
                                <td>{$row['game_name']}</td>

                                <td>";
                                $query="SELECT * FROM genre WHERE genre_id=".$row['game_genrea']; 
                                $genrearesult=mysqli_query($link,$query);                                   $genrearow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($genrearesult);
                            echo $genrearow['genre_name'];
                            echo "</td>
                                <td>{$row['game_dev']}</td>
                                <td>{$row['game_pub']}</td>
                                <td>{$row['game_site']}</td>
                            </tr>";


                           }

                           echo"</table>";
```

The last tabel data ($row['game_site']} echoes the URL right now, but I would like to have an image appear(ie a browser icon) that links to to the echoed website and which is saved in my images folder. Is that possible? I tried different syntaxes, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data being executed is a url, you will have to use some html to make it the href of an anchor tag and then provide an image inside the anchor tag to get what you want.

```
<td><a href=\"{$row['game_site']}\"><img src=\"IMAGE_URL_GOES_HERE\" /></a></td>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works flawlessly, although the images, which I manually resized to 30x30 before putting in the images folder, automatically resizes itself to 96x96 to fill the aforementioned width of 100px. Any idea how to prevent that from happening? I tried adding height=\30px\ but that didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Insert: style=\"height:30px;\" inside the image tag.

Comment: Eventually added it to the table itself, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
echo "<td><a href='".$row['game_site']."'> <img src='image.gif'/></a></td>";
```

note the "a" tag with href

Comment: I think you are on the wrong tag here! Here is PHP not JS

Comment: haha sorry meant to put periods as opposed to + for concatenation. and yes I have been using js lately.